# Bulk Upload Account Performance

Tags: sql, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq

I am trying to refactor the bulk upload performance in Job, as now it is taking lot of account upload time which is affecting db load and performance. can some one please help me ConfirmPendingAccountsJob (at least 50,000 accounts)  is able to accept large numbers of accounts and process them efficiently

```
  def confirm_pending_account(account_upload)
    ConfirmPendingAccountsJob.perform_later(account_upload: account_upload)
  end
```

```
  class ConfirmPendingAccountsJob < BaseJob
    queue_as :low_priority

    attr_reader :accounts, :account_upload

    def perform(account_upload:)
      @account_upload = account_upload
      pending_accounts = account_upload.pending_accounts.not_failed

      @accounts = {
        previously_existing: [],
        newly_created: []
      }

      pending_accounts.each do |pending_account|
        # TODO: Find duplicates in bulk
        duplicate_account_in_same_organisation = pending_account.find_duplicate
        if duplicate_account_in_same_organisation
          accounts[:previously_existing] << [pending_account, duplicate_account_in_same_organisation]
          next
        end

        # Verified is set before this job is run; the next line is only needed in order to run this
        # job in isolation, from the command line, otherwise all account creation will be skipped
        # pending_account.account_verified!
        next unless pending_account.verified? # Failure already recorded by VerifyPendingAccountJob

        created_account = pending_account.create_account_with_errors
        if created_account.errors.any?
          pending_account.record_failure!(serialized_errors: created_account.errors.to_hash)
        else
          accounts[:newly_created] << [pending_account, created_account]
        end
      end

      finalise_accounts_creation
    end

    private

    def finalise_accounts_creation
      move_into_teams_and_licences

      accounts[:previously_existing].each do |bundle|
        update_pending_account(bundle.pending_account, bundle.account, status: :updated)
      end

      accounts[:newly_created].each do |pending_account, account|
        update_pending_account(pending_account, account, status: :created)
        account.confirm
      end
    end

    def move_into_teams_and_licences
      Team.find(account_upload.team_ids).each do |team|
        team.add_accounts(all_accounts)
      end

      Licensing::Public::API.find_licence(account_upload.licence_ids).each do |licence|
        licence.bulk_enrol_accounts(all_accounts)
      end

      EventPublisher.account_licences_changed(all_accounts)
    end

    def update_pending_account(pending_account, account, status:)
      if status == :created
        pending_account.create_account!
      else
        pending_account.update_account!
      end
      # This establishes the link from an account to a pending account
      pending_account.update!(account: account)
    end

    def all_accounts
      newly_created_accounts + previously_existing_accounts
    end

    def previously_existing_accounts
      @accounts[:previously_existing].map{|bundle| bundle.account }
    end

    def newly_created_accounts
      @accounts[:newly_created].map{|_,account| account }
    end
  end
```

I want to send batches of accounts to downstream methods (most importantly team.add_accounts but also licence.bulk_enrol_accounts) to enable more efficient processing.

Want to handle batching in a same way, so that the job can accept an arbitrary number of accounts but individual jobs will process a manageable number.

If necessary to protect the DB, the job will also accept parameters for batch size and delay between batches to enable

Comment: I'm not sure that you have an answerable question here. It sounds like you would like to have someone evaluate and refactor your code so that it is more performant. The issues with that request are: 1) That's not a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) because it doesn't include debugging details and is very broad. 2) There is no [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). *You* need to do the work to make in minimal and reproducible by others. 3) It has multiple questions in one: you have at least three separate requests.

Comment: I don't think that you're likely to get an answer to this question the way that it's written now. I urge you to read the article [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a sense of what kinds of questions are likely to receive answers. You have a very complex problem here that I believe can be broken down into smaller, simpler problems that are both answerable and likely to be answered. The more you can do to make your questions straightforward and clear, the more likely you are to get help.